# Python - Regex pattern matching issue after executing a sqlite query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, regex, sqlite

I am trying to extract some information from one table and store it in another table using Sqlite and Python.  Table 1 contains a list of websites in the form of (www.abc.com).  I am trying to extract the (abc) part from each row and store it in Table 2 which also maintains a count for each site.  If the site already exist in Table 2, then it just increment the count.

Here the code I have:

```
p = re.compile('^.+\.([a-zA-Z]+)\..+$')
for row in c.execute('SELECT links FROM table1'):
    link = p.match(row[0])

    if link.group(1):
        print(link.group(1))
        c.execute('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE site_name = ?)', (link.group(1), ))
```

When I run the script, it will only execute once, then I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 43, in <module>
      link = p.match(row[0])
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

If I comment out the c.execute line, all the site names are printed properly.  I am new to Python and Sqlite, so I am not sure what the problem is.

Any help will be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is that `c.execute` line there? You're iterating over a cursor, and then you tell that cursor to do a different query in the middle of the one you're iterating. What did you want to happen there?

Comment: Don't know about SQLite stuff, but your regex requires at least 3 parts with 2 periods. You could be more flexible if it were `^(?:.+\.)?([a-zA-Z]+)\..+$`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're iterating over a cursor whose rows contain a single string:

```
for row in c.execute('SELECT links FROM table1'):
```

… but then, in the middle of the iteration, you change it into a cursor whose rows consist of a single number:

```
    c.execute('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE site_name = ?)', (link.group(1), ))
```

So, when you get the next row, it's going to be `[1]` instead of `['http://example.com']`, so `p.match(row[0])` is passing the number `1` to `match`, and it's complaining that `1` is not a string or buffer.

---

For future reference, it's really helpful to debug things by looking at the intermediate values. Whether you run in the debugger, or just add `print(row)` calls and the like to log what's going on, you'd know that it works the first time through the loop, but that it fails the second time, and that `row` looked like `[1]` when it failed. That would make it much easier for you to track down the problem (or allow you to ask a better question on SO, because obviously you still won't be able to find everything yourself.)

---

You could fix this in (at least) three ways, in increasing order of "goodness if appropriate":

- Fetch all of the values from the first query, then loop over those, so your second query doesn't get in the way.
- Use a separate cursor for each query, instead of reusing the same one.
- Don't make the second query in the first place—it's a `SELECT` query and you aren't doing anything with the rows, so what good is it doing?

Answer (score 0):

The inner execute is probably stepping on your cursor iterator state. Try creating a second cursor object for that query.